# Change font size in Table

Tags: tables, fontsize

How do I change the font size in my table?

I have tried the `\normalsize` and `\small` commands, but it doesnt make any difference. I needed to specify column length to get the design I wanted, does this have something to do with it?

Here is a part of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h] 
    \caption[text} 
    \label{Tsomething} 
    \centering

    \renewcommand\arraystretch{2} 
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
    {% \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|p{15cm}|p{15cm}|c|@{}} 
    \toprule 
    \textbf{Resource} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Application} & \textbf{Comment} \\
    \midrule 
    bla. & bla & bla &  \\ 
    \midrule 
    bla. & bla & bla & \\ 
    \midrule 
    bla. & bla & bla & \\ 
    \midrule 
    bla. & bla & bla & \\ 
    \midrule 
    bla. & bla & bla &  \\ 
    \midrule 
    bla. & bla & bla & \\ 
    \midrule bla. & bla & bla & \\ 
    \midrule bla. & bla & bla & \\ 
    \bottomrule \end{tabular}% } 
    \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

I have some long sentences in the table, and i want latex to put these in several lines, instead of minimizing the font size to put it all in the same line. This is why i dont use the following code (then i can barely see the text).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h] 
    \caption[text} 
    \label{Tsomething} 
    \centering

    \renewcommand\arraystretch{2} 
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
    {% \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|c|@{}} 
    \toprule 
    \textbf{Resource} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{Application} & \textbf{Comment} \\
    \midrule 
    bla. & bla & bla &  \\ 
    \midrule 
    bla. & bla & bla & \\ 
    \midrule 
    bla. & bla & bla & \\ 
    \midrule 
    bla. & bla & bla & \\ 
    \midrule 
    bla. & bla & bla &  \\ 
    \midrule 
    bla. & bla & bla & \\ 
    \midrule bla. & bla & bla & \\ 
    \midrule bla. & bla & bla & \\ 
    \bottomrule \end{tabular}% } 
    \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you please add a fully compilable MWE?

Comment: Well, what do you expect at a table more than 30 cm wide (longer than the length of an A4 sheet)? Why is it necessary to have 15cm in those columns?

Comment: (i) your code snippet contain errors, (ii) provide more realistic content of table; from presented follows, that you not need `p{...}` columns type (iii) vertical lines and rules from `booktabs` should not be used together, (why you need so big stretch of table , ... etc. please provide complete small document (mwe: minimal working example) beginning with  `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.with example of one or two real rows (simulated by dummy, but equal long text).

Comment: Raaja: Sorry, i hope the code is compilable now. 
JouleV: You are right, i dont want a table of 30 cm. I want latex to put line breaks in automatically so the text is not supersmall and unreadable.
Zarko: can you please elaborate which errors you refer to? I am unfamiliar with using dummy variables, but i will try to make one.
Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you might looking for the following result:

[image]

table width is equal to text width, font size is `\small`, widths of the second and third columns are equal and determined automatically by package `tabular

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{text}
\label{Tsomething}
    \centering
    \small
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}c L L c@{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Resource}
    & \textbf{Type}
        & \textbf{Application}
            & \textbf{Comment}  \\ 
    \midrule
bla.    & \lipsum[1][1-3] & \lipsum[1][1-3] &       \\ 
bla.    & bla           & bla   &       \\ 
bla.    & bla           & bla   &       \\ 
bla.    & bla           & bla   &       \\ 
bla.    & bla           & bla   &       \\ 
bla.    & bla           & bla   &       \\ 
bla.    & bla           & bla   &       \\ 
bla.    & bla           & bla   &       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```